# Selecting objects that are associated with similar datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select all company rows from a [Company] table that share with at least one other company, the same number of employees (from an [Employee] table that has a CompanyId column), where each group of respective employees share the same set of LocationIds (a column in the [Employee] table) and in the same proportion.

So, for instance, two companies with three employees each that have the locationIds 1,2, and 2, would be selected by this query.

```
[Employee]

 EmployeeId |  CompanyId  | LocationId | 
========================================
  1         |  1          |  1      
  2         |  1          |  2 
  3         |  1          |  2
  4         |  2          |  1 
  5         |  2          |  2 
  6         |  2          |  2 
  7         |  3          |  3



[Company]

 CompanyId | 
============
  1   |     
  2   |    
  3   |


  Returns the CompanyIds:
  ======================
  1
  2
```

CompanyIds 1 and 2 are selected because they share in common with at least one other company: 1. the number of employees (3 employees); and 2. the number/proportion of LocationIds associated with those employees (1 employee has LocationId 1 and 2 employees have LocationId 2).

So far I think I want to use a `HAVING COUNT(?) > 1` statement, but I'm having trouble working out the details. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How about some details? This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. Need some sample data and expected outputs.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I've added some tables to be example.

Comment: OK so you added the employee table. What is the logic of this query? Your rules don't make a lot of sense to me. And not really sure what the company table has to do with this.

Comment: I've added more information regarding the expected results beneath the tables. Let me know if that doesn't clarify what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but the only way I can think of to do it:

```
;with CTE as (
    select c.Id,
        (
            select e.Location, count(e.Id) [EmployeeCount]
            from Employee e
            where e.IdCompany=c.Id
            group by e.Location
            order by e.Location
            for xml auto
        ) LocationEmployeeData
    from Company c
)
select c.Id
from Company c
join (
    select x.LocationEmployeeData, count(x.Id) [CompanyCount]
    from CTE x
    group by x.LocationEmployeeData
    having count(x.Id) >= 2
) y on y.LocationEmployeeData = (select LocationEmployeeData from CTE where Id = c.Id)
```

See fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bc16/5

It works by encoding the Employee count per Location data (multiple rows) into an xml string for each Company.

The CTE code on its own:

```
select c.Id,
    (
        select e.Location, count(e.Id) [EmployeeCount]
        from Employee e
        where e.IdCompany=c.Id
        group by e.Location
        order by e.Location
        for xml auto
    ) LocationEmployeeData
from Company c
```

Produces data like:

```
Id  LocationEmployeeData
1   <e Location="1" EmployeeCount="2"/><e Location="2" EmployeeCount="1"/>
2   <e Location="1" EmployeeCount="2"/><e Location="2" EmployeeCount="1"/>
3   <e Location="3" EmployeeCount="1"/>
```

Then it compares companies based on this string (rather than trying to ascertain whether multiple rows match, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Would this scale well? For instance, say I have around 10,000 companies with about 1000 employees each. Would such a query be capable of executing under 'semi-high performance conditions' in roughly 24 hours?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to take anywhere near 24 hours, but you would really need to test it to find out how performant it is under real load with real data. The CTE data is not cached, but executed whenever it's referenced, so there's probably improvements to be made here. You could use a temp table to store the CTE data, for example.

Comment: Thanks, it's looking like this will work. One last question: is there any easy way of excluding from the results, those companies with no employees?

Comment: Actually, it looks like [it does that already!](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3daeb/1) I guess it's the `inner join` on the CTE which selects from Employee - no Employee, no row.

Comment: Oops. My oversight. Thanks a ton for all of your help on this! Seeing the solutions here, I'm sure I couldn't have come to this on my own in any reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could look like this. However it also requires performance testing in advance (I don't feel quite confident with `<>` type join).

```
with List as
(
  select
    IdCompany,
    Location,
    row_number() over (partition by IdCompany order by Location) as RowId,
    count(1) over (partition by IdCompany) as LocCount
  from
    Employee
) 
select
  A.IdCompany
from List as A
  inner join List as B on A.IdCompany <> B.IdCompany
  and A.RowID = B.RowID
  and A.LocCount = B.LocCount
group by
  A.IdCompany, A.LocCount
having
  sum(case when A.Location = B.Location then 1 else 0 end) = A.LocCount
```

Related fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9f2e/1

Comment: Intuitively, I like your solution better than mine. I expect it to be faster, and `for xml` felt dirty anyway. I'd be interesting in seeing performance comparisons on a large dataset though!

Comment: Quick update: this isn't a formal performance test or anything, but the 'for xml' approach (above) took about 30 secs to execute on my dataset, and I canceled this '<> join' after about 3 mins. I was a bit surprised by the result. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I am not suprised. If you have 10,000 customers and there is no much variation in number of locations in each of them, then this produces tremendous number of combinations unfortunately.